# Material UI layout grid less than 12 column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a grid layout which my idea is to separate column to 10 but not 12. Enlarge the default column number is able to find on internet. But the way of reduce the column number cannot be found.

Is that impossible to do it? or should I use another way to do it?

Here is my [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gridlessthan12-epiog?file=/src/App.js)

- I have try to use other method like row 2, 3, 4 in sandbox. Of course,there is only 10 chip per row which is what I am expected. However, the width still cannot be fully utilize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you were trying to keep 10 chip per row with equal spacer and utilizing full width of the page.

`justify="space-between"` make your chips align with equal spacer.

`<Grid container spacing={1} justify="space-between">` is the change you need.

Comment: You assumption is right. However, if I use justify="space-between" only, 12*<Grid> will still in the same row. Is there a way which will auto swap row when there is 10 <Grid>?
(I can do it if I use <Grid xs={12}> 10*Grid </Grid> +  <Grid xs={12}> 2*Grid </Grid>, is this the only way to achieve my target?)

Comment: Yes I think so, these Grid system is implment standard that you can not change default num of columns from 12. Even many other grid system uses 12 as standard.

Comment: Oh....Thank for your help. Your answers help me a lot!